# re rendering angular ui-boostrap datepicker inconsistency

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

when re-rendering the datepicker-popup directive, ui-datepicker doesn't seem to take into account the previously selected model value.

Please take a look to this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7JDJhacNMMOpVuLLzYSM?p=preview), pick a date, then toogle the checkbox two times to remove and recreate the datepicker form field.

**datepicker form field value changed from 2014-12-14 to Sun Dec 14 2014 16:21:46 GMT+0100 (CET)**

```
<form class="form" name="test">
          <legend>Anuglar ui datepicker and ng-if Test</legend>
          <div  class="form-group">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mymodel.namespace.showDate"/>
              Show date
            </label>
            <pre>{{mymodel.namespace.date}}</pre>
          </div>
          <div  class="form-group"
                ng-if="mymodel.namespace.showDate === true "
          >

            <input 
              class="form-control" 
              name="date" 
              type="text" 
              ng-model="mymodel.namespace.date" 
              show-weeks="false" 
              show-button-bar="false" 
              is-open="calendarOpened" 
              ng-required="true" 
              ng-click="calendarOpened=true" 
              datepicker-popup />
          </div>
        </form>



// JS
app = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])


app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.mymodel = {
    namespace: {
      date: new Date(),
      showDate: true
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is that you are describing.  Every time I click on a date, and then click off the picker to close the picker, and then click back on the text box to reopen the picker the date I previously selected is present.

Comment: sorry my bad didn't record the last version of the plunk, updated now if you want to take a look

Comment: opened a github issue https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3124

Answer (score 0):

I was able to duplicate your error and fix it.

This line

Changes to

```
<div  class="form-group" ng-show="mymodel.namespace.showDate === true ">
```

The difference between the two is that with an ng-if each time the statement evaluates to true it will rerender that element.  With an ng-show it is similar to using CSS to hide it.

I find that if all I am trying to do is hide an element until it is needed I will use ng-show.  If I want to prevent an element from rendering I will us ng-if.

Comment: You're right the issue really deals with re-rendering, i'll improve the description